# CakePHP- Using the JsHelper for Ajax Search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Ok, So I am trying to implement sort of a livesearch using the cake's Js Helper. The user will select a  criteria to search by, using a drop down, and then tyoe in his search in an input text field. So far, this is what I have.

```
   echo $this->Form->create(false,array('type'=>'post','default'=>false));
        echo $this->Form->input('criteria',array(
                'label'=>'Search Criteria',
                'options' => array(
                    'id'=> 'By ID',
                    'name' => 'By Name',
                    'blood' => 'By Blood Type',
                    'type' => 'By Donor Type',
                    'age' => 'By Age',
                    'gender' => 'By Gender' 
                )
            ));
         ?>
```

Here is the input:

```
 <?php  echo $this->Form->input('query', array('type' => 'text', 'id' => 'query', 'name' => 'query', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Search')); ?>
    <div id="loading" style="display: none; ">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('ajax_clock.gif');?>
    </div>
```

And this is my Js code generated using the helper!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   <?php   
      echo $this->Js->get('#query')->event('keyup',$this->Js->request(  
            array('controller' => 'donors', 'action' => 'search'),  
            array('update'=>'#results','async' => true,'dataExpression' => true,'method' => 'post','data'=>'$(\'#query,#criteria\').serializeArray()')  
            ),false);  
    ?>
    </script>
```

The above Js should grab the values of the criteria drop down aswell as the value inside the input field , on the keyup event. That said, I thought it was better to encode the data, and found the serializeArray method in the doc, which should do just that (I think..)

Now, my problem is I do not know how to retrieve that serialized data from the action receiving the request. So far I have this

```
function search() {
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
    }
}
```

So basically, I want to know how to access the data from the search action, as well as, I tried to echo the $data variable, and die($data), but I do not know where the debugging info is displayed. Any help regarding both my questions would be MUCH appreciated! thanks!

Comment: see firebug console for output data

Comment: @Anubhav, sorry for being unclear.. I was asking whether I can view results with DebugKit